# Run command line program through python

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to run a program (that can be run entirely through command line) through python.

The program will then run and wait for inputs.

I can give the inputs manually but I am trying to automate the process by feeding the inputs through the python script. I don't need to know the output to give an input. The input is predetermined.

**This is what I've got so far**:

```
def enterProgram():
    # p = subprocess.call(link, shell=True)
    p = subprocess.Popen(link, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate()
    p.stdin.write(querynew1)
```

This code just runs the program and exits it without considering my input at all.

- link is the path to the program
- querynew1 is my input after the program initializes and waits for an input.

Please advice as to how I can solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: `p.communicate()` ends subprocess. You need to keep writing and reading (be careful to not fall into deadlock) and call `communicate()` after your last input. But I recommend you to look at `pyexpect` module instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info on p.communicate(). Can I also check with you if I have to alternate writing and reading? Is it possible to only write? Also I am not very clear as to how the pipes work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that should do it

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(link, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout.read())
```

Comment: i tried that but it just exited the process. it did not run the program. is there a way i can keep sending lines of command to the command line after i open the program using either subprocess.call or subprocess.Popen?

Comment: oh ok, I thought you wanted just to have output spit out after the execution

Answer (score 0):

`Popen.communicate()` takes input as an argument. If you need to provide input only once, and read output only once, this should do it:

```
def enterProgram():
    p = subprocess.Popen(link, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate(querynew1)
    return out
```